# Backup / Restore Coredata (sqlite)

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data, backup, restore

I have a standard iOS coredata application (sqlite). Users are requesting that they be able to backup and restore from backup their data. Can anybody tell me how to do so? Or some links where this is explained in detail? I don't mind using iTunes file sharing but would like to know how to implement this.

Also if the user restores a database if the database is not correct it should be rejected before replacing the existing database. I have searched the internet for this but did not find any examples.

Comment: ANy development on this? I'd like to do the same on my private web server by saving remotely the sqlite but would like to know if there is any best practice...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend iCloud. iCloud API is intended to work with Core Data sqlite databases. For more information read [Using Core Data with iCloud Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011298).